# android jni native crash: Runtime aborting...art::Thread::Init IndirectReferenceTable

Tags: android, crash, native

When I run my app for several hours, it crashes and shows the logcat info as follows:

```
Runtime aborting...

( 1197): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289] Aborting thread:

( 1197): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289] "<native thread without managed peer>" prio=5 tid=80 Native (still starting up)


( 1197): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x0 self=0xa2afa000

( 1197): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   | sysTid=2898 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xa201e800

( 1197): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   | state=R schedstat=( 4000000 0 3 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=6 HZ=100

( 1197): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   | stack=0x9b1e3000-0x9b1e5000 stackSize=1036KB

( 1197): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   | held mutexes= "abort lock" "mutator lock"(shared held)

( 1197): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #00 pc 00004ef0  /system/lib/libbacktrace_libc++.so (UnwindCurrent::Unwind(unsigned int, ucontext*)+23)

( 1197): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #01 pc 000036d5  /system/lib/libbacktrace_libc++.so (Backtrace::Unwind(unsigned int, ucontext*)+8)

( 1197): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #02 pc 002439d1  /system/lib/libart.so (art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, int, char const*, art::mirror::ArtMethod*)+68)

( 1197): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #03 pc 00227d79  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) const+144)

( 1197): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #04 pc 00217eef  /system/lib/libart.so (art::AbortState::DumpThread(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, art::Thread*)+22)

( 1197): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #05 pc 00218155  /system/lib/libart.so (art::AbortState::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&)+364)

( 1197): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #06 pc 00218321  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort()+72)

( 1197): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #07 pc 000a6e7b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+1322)

( 1197): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #08 pc 0015860f  /system/lib/libart.so (art::IndirectReferenceTable::IndirectReferenceTable(unsigned int, unsigned int, art::IndirectRefKind)+402)

( 1197): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #09 pc 00195e2d  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JNIEnvExt::JNIEnvExt(art::Thread*, art::JavaVMExt*)+24)

( 1197): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #10 pc 0022722f  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::Init(art::ThreadList*, art::JavaVMExt*)+338)

( 1197): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #11 pc 0022a785  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::CreateCallback(void*)+84)

( 1197): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #12 pc 00016ea3  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+30)

( 1197): art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]   native: #13 pc 00014deb  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+6)
```

It seems to be a `IndirectReferenceTable` overflow problem. But how do I get the location of the problem?

Anyone else experienced this or know of a fix?